# Using NDSolveValue for Solving a parabolic PDE numerically

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4352292/993738) question I am trying to solve the following PDE numerically on $x \in [-3, 3]$ and $t \in [0, 0.5]$ using NDSolveValue:

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = (12x^2-4) p + \left[4x(x^2-1)+0.1\right] \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{\beta} \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} \\
$$

The initial condition is $p(x,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})$ and the zero boundary condition is $p(-3,t)=p(3,t)=0$.

As a first orientation I looked at the approach described by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/solving-2d1-pde-with-pseudospectral-in-one-direction-with-periodic-boundary-con) entitled *"Solving 2D+1 PDE with Pseudospectral in one direction with periodic boundary condition?"* and used:

```
b = 200;
pval = NDSolveValue[{D[p[x,t],t] == (12x^2-4)p[x,t]+(4x(x^2-1)+0.1) *
   D[p[x,t],x] + D[p[x,t]/b, {x,2}], p[x,0] == Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2Pi],
       p[-3,t] == 0, p[3,t] == 0}, p, {x,-3,3}, {t,0,0.5}];

ContourPlot[pval[i,j], {i,-3,3}, {j,0,0.5}]
```

After choosing $b=-200$, $b=-1$, $b=1$ and $b=200$, it generated the following Contour Plots:

[image]

***My problem/question:***

Unfortunatelly the zero boundary condition doesn't seem to hold, since we should have $p(−3,t)=p(3,t)=0$ for any $t$. Something I am doing wrong and it would be great if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MethodOfLines` gives a solution to your problem:

```
b = 200;
P = NDSolveValue[{D[p[x, t],t] == (12 x^2 - 4) p[x, t] + (4 x (x^2 - 1) + 0.1)*D[p[x, t], x] + D[p[x, t]/b, {x, 2}], 
p[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi], p[-3, t] == 0, p[3, t] == 0}, 
p, {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 0.5}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}];

Plot3D[P[x, t], {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, .5}]
```

[image]

The boundary conditions aren't fullfilled exactly, because boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.

inconsistence might be removed if you change the initial conditions to `p[x, 0] ==  Which[0 < RealAbs[x] <= 3, Min[(3 - RealAbs[x])/.01, 1], True, 0] Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi]`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much - your solution is very useful.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @EldarSultanow and Ulrich: The critical part is not `MethodOfLines` (Eldar's code also uses it under the hood, and this is the only available method built in `NDSolve` for time dependent problem at the moment, but the sub-option is `TensorProduct` by default in this case, related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140773/1871 ), but `FiniteElement`. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230429/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for the hint. Please show your solution proposal using "TensorProductGrid", would be very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

OK, let me extend my comment to an answer. First of all, I'd like to point out that OP's observation

> the zero boundary condition doesn't seem to hold

isn't really a problem here. Though `ibcinc` warning does pop up, and the zero boundary condition is not **exactly** hold, the error is rather small in this case. For more info you may refer to the [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871). The real problem here, is the `eerr` warning pops up and the corresponding error is so large (it's `280235.11872106727`! ) that we cannot ignore it.

Then why does the estimated error so large? In short, this problem is quite similar with [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230429/1871) i.e. naive spatial discretization won't *work* for the PDE and we need to **respect** the conservation law in some way when discretizing. The simplest solution is to, as shown by Ulrich in his answer, turn to `FiniteElement` method, but still, we can use `TensorProductGrid` method. We just need to transform the PDE a little and set a low `DifferenceOrder`:

```
With[{p = p[x, t], mid = mid[x, t]},
 eq = D[p, t] == D[mid, x];
 eqadd = mid == (4 x (x^2 - 1) + 0.1) p + D[p/b, x];]
ic = p[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi];
icadd = mid[x, 0] == eqadd[[-1]] /. p -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@ic[[-1]]];
bc = {p[-3, t] == 0, p[3, t] == 0};

mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

tst = NDSolveValue[{eq, eqadd, ic, icadd, bc}, p, {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 0.5}, 
    Method -> mol[300, 2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The `eerr` warning still pops up, but the corresponding error (`815.9` ) isn't too large. Let's check how it looks like:

```
Plot3D[tst[i, j], {i, -3, 3}, {j, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[tst[i, 0.5], {i, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks reasonable, and it's consistent with that of FEM. Further check shows, the solution doesn't change significantly even if we make the grid denser, so it's probably reliable.

---

### Update

Aha, the magic of `Pseudospectral` seems to be effective for this problem:

```
b = 200;
pval = NDSolveValue[{D[p[x, t], 
      t] == (12 x^2 - 4) p[x, t] + (4 x (x^2 - 1) + 0.1) D[p[x, t], x] + 
      D[p[x, t]/b, {x, 2}], p[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi], p[-3, t] == 0, 
    p[3, t] == 0}, p, {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 0.5}, Method -> mol[401]];
Plot[pval[i, 0.5], {i, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

It's not necessary to modify the form of PDE even if `TensorProductGrid` is chosen!

Comment: Thank you very much for your extended comment. `PseudoSpectral`  has "saved" the method `TensorProductGrid`( ;-) ). But FiniteElement seems to be significantly faster (factor 6)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Which version are you in? In _v12.3.1_, _win10_, the timing of `mol[401]`  and `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01` is 0.736 seconds v.s. 5.86 seconds, and precision of FEM is worse near the boundary.

Comment: My version is v12.2 Win10.