# Table of function derivative evaluation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, list-manipulation

I want to create a table with numerical values of a function derivative by using the following code:

```
f[x_, a_] := f[x, a] = Tanh[a (1 - Cos[x])];
g[x_, a_] := g[x, a] = D[f[x, a], x];
pderivative = Table[{x, Evaluate[g[x, 5]]}, {x, - π,  π, 2 π/500.}]
```

When I look at the result, it's not what I expect. Any trick to fix this?
[image]

Comment: `g = D[f[x, a], x]; pderivative = 
 Table[{x, g /. a -> 5}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/500.}]`

Comment: 1. As mentioned by Henrik in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180369/how-to-accelerate-ndsolve-for-pde-with-user-defined-functions#comment471546_180369), memoization for functions with real arguments is usually rather pointless as the chances that exactly the same pops up somewhere else are rather low. 2. Don't abuse `SetDelayed`(`:=`). Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181586/1871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method I**

Define your `g` by `Derivative` instead of `D`:

```
g[x_, a_] := g[x, a] = Derivative[1, 0][f][x, a];
```

Note that `Evaluate` in `pderivative` is not a necessity.

---

**Method II**

Alternatively it also works in this way:

```
g[x_, a_] = D[f[x, a], x]
```

FYI, please check [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487) concerning the difference between `Set (=)` and `SetDelayed (:=)`.

Comment: Many thanks! Is this due to two variables?

Comment: @BobLin No, see my update.

Comment: Why you take the derivative with respect to $a$?

Comment: @BobLin Oh, sorry, just a typo; Corrected.